# Beta Testing, External Testing Status is inactive

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect, testflight, beta-testing

My App is Ready for sale but, i have uploaded a new version, in prerelease tab external testing status shows inactive, how do i active external testers.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/SettingUpUserAccounts.html This should tell you everything you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many things that you have to look into, when publishing an app.

Apple provided very good and thoriugh documentation.

You can find everything you need [over here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/SettingUpUserAccounts.html)